# Best way to set configuration to a database

Tags: java, mysql, database, configuration, passwords

First, this is not a programming question, yes I know.

Now, I am developing a custom software (Java Swing) for a company as a sub contracting company. I create the code and database (MySQL), send them via a protected method online and their IT people install it there by them selves. I cannot reach their place as I am in a far far away city.

I am having a problem with the database, that is, should I hard-code the database configurations into the Java swing application (or .properties file) or else should I allow the user to decide the password, user name and server IP ? Which means user can edit them at any time, I am planning to use `java.util.pref.Preferences` in that case.

However I have heard that lot of development companies do not allow the user to edit the password, user name etc, mainly because they might go and edit the database.

So right now I am confused. which method should I select? Hard coding the configurations or allowing dynamic configurations? Any advice please?

Comment: Why not a simple configuration file? Even an [INI file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) is better than nothing, but a JSON or YAML file works just as well.

Comment: @tadman: Not clear pls?

Comment: The problem with storing configuration in your database is how do you configure where your database is? It's a [catch-22](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_(logic)). A simple text file is often the best option here unless you have really complicated properties. The Java `.properties` type files are familiar to developers but may be difficult for end users to work with, XML is unfamiliar territory for many. There's no way to lock down the database, you can just make it annoying for people to find out the password.

Comment: @tadman: Database will be saved in client's server. They access via VPN. Currently the application is set to "root" so I am afraid that someone could go and edit the structure.

Comment: First thing you do is make a more restrictive account for each user. Using `root` is completely reckless.

Comment: As tadman mentioned,its a bad idea to provide root access.

Comment: @Balaram26: Sure. But I am not the person who is "installing" the DB. But I can hard code the user name and password.

Comment: In that case,the root username and password is selected by the user who instals the DB. Then rather than hard coding those details,u can instruct the admin to start the software after installation is completed,give option to set root access details of the db in your software and make sure its a one time thing. This way whoever is the admin can set up the db and software settings initially.